# How to use "addContentView" in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I want to draw some pictures through " view.addContentView(dCircle, lParams)" in Fragment, but there are some problems with it. AndroidStudio says Variable "view" is accessed from within class,needs to be declared final.

How can I solve it?

**My Code**

```
public class FragmentHome extends BaseFragment {
    public static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "fragment";

private SelfCheck_Draw_Circle dCircle;
public static List<SelfCheck_Draw_Circle> saveCircle;
 ……
 ……
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 700);
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    initImageLoader(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selfcheck_main_tab, container, false);
 ……
 ……
    draw_btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonadd);
    draw_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveCircle = new ArrayList<>();
            dCircle = new SelfCheck_Draw_Circle(**getApplicationContext()**);
            **view.addContentView**(dCircle, lParams);
            saveCircle.add(dCircle);
        }
    });
 ……
 ……
    });

    return view;
}

 ……
 ……
```

Comment: do it `view.addView(dCircle, lParams);`

Comment: why are you using addContentView(), it is like setContentView check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#addContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)

Comment: Add final keyword in view declaration: final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selfcheck_main_tab, container, false);

Comment: This is a Fragment, when I add final keyword in view declaration, it still says: can not resolve method "addContentView()". Why?
 'view.addContentView(dCircle, lParams);'